# Is there an idiomatic way to return a pointer that optionally owns its value

Tags: c++, stl

I have a function that given a path name, does a look up and returns a pointer to the associated value. Sometimes the value lives in a static cache, sometimes it gets calculated and created on the fly.

So, sometimes the caller takes ownership and needs to delete the object after reading it, and sometimes not. I'm wondering, is there something I can wrap this pointer with so that it will automatically be freed as necessary by the caller?

I was thinking I might be able to use a unique_ptr, but isn't the deleter part of the type, so how could I return the same type that sometimes does and sometimes doesn't actually delete.

Comment: Wouldn't a `shared_ptr` do the trick? If the value lives in the cache, then the caller will get its shared pointer to that value that won't delete anything when going out of scope, and if it doesn't and the callers actually has ownership of the value just created, then it'll be deleted when the shared pointer goes out of scope.

Comment: It might. However, the static cache doesn't user shared_ptr's, it stores values. I am thinking I could use a shared_ptr with a no-op deleter for returning pointers to those values. And a shared_ptr with a deleter for the values that get calculated on the fly.

Comment: Oh right, I realized afterwards that if the cache doesn't actually use pointers, that's not as simple. Yes, in this case this looks like a working approach. And it's completely transparent to the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So indeed, one solution could be returning a normal `std::shared_ptr` for the value created inside the function, and another one with an empty deleter for the value that lives in the map.

[**Live example of this solution**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93954b4d01a4c9d8)

You can see how both use cases don't require any actions from the calling code and are completely transparent.

Comment: You don't need an empty deleter. Just make the map hold `shared_ptr`'s as well, and it will be achieved automatically via ref counting.

Comment: @DarkWanderer The problem is, apparently OP has _values_ and not pointers in his map. That would've been easier indeed (and was my first idea) but that doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `std::shared_ptr` but that does not really describe your ownership model. Have you considered rolling your own wrapper that contains a `std::unique_ptr` and a raw pointer and uses the correct one depending on the circumstances? Something like:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class MyClass { };

class Wrapper {
  const MyClass*           cached_;
  std::unique_ptr<MyClass> owned_;
 public:
  Wrapper() : cached_(nullptr) {}
  void setCached(const MyClass* cached) {cached_ = cached;}
  void setOwned(std::unique_ptr<MyClass> owned) { owned_ = std::move(owned); }
  const MyClass* get() const {return cached_ ? cached_ : owned_.get();}
};

Wrapper getWrapper(int i) {
  static MyClass first;
  static MyClass second;

  Wrapper wrapper;

  if (i == 0)
    wrapper.setCached(&first);
  else if (i == 1)
    wrapper.setCached(&second);
  else
    wrapper.setOwned(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass()));

  return wrapper;
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i) {
    Wrapper wrapper = getWrapper(i);
    assert(wrapper.get() != nullptr);
  }
}
```

The wrapper can either forward calls to the real class or provide access to a raw pointer to the real class.

Or the wrapper could work polymorphically, with an interface and two implementations. One with a raw pointer and one with a unique pointer:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class MyClass {};

class Wrapper {
 public:
  virtual ~Wrapper() = 0; 
  virtual const MyClass* get() const = 0;   
};

Wrapper::~Wrapper() {}

class OwnerWrapper : public Wrapper {
  std::unique_ptr<MyClass> owned_;
 public:
  OwnerWrapper(std::unique_ptr<MyClass> in) : owned_(std::move(in)) {}
  virtual const MyClass* get() const { return owned_.get(); }
};

class PtrWrapper : public Wrapper {
  const MyClass* ptr_;
 public:
  PtrWrapper(const MyClass* ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}
  virtual const MyClass* get() const { return ptr_; }
};

std::unique_ptr<Wrapper> getWrapper(int i) {
  static MyClass first;
  static MyClass second;

  if (i == 0)
    return std::unique_ptr<Wrapper>(new PtrWrapper(&first));
  else if (i == 1)
    return std::unique_ptr<Wrapper>(new PtrWrapper(&second));
  else {
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> myclass(new MyClass());
    return std::unique_ptr<Wrapper>(new OwnerWrapper(std::move(myclass)));
  }
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i) {
    auto wrapper = getWrapper(i);
    assert(wrapper->get() != nullptr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::unique_ptr` with a deleter that knows whether to free or not.  While the deleter *type* is part of the `unique_ptr` type, different unique_ptr instances can have different deleter instances:

```
template <class T>
class delete_if_not_cached {
    bool cached;
public:
    delete_if_not_cached(bool c = false) : cached(c) {}
    void operator()(T *obj) { if (!cached) delete obj; }
}
```

and you have your function return a `std::unique_ptr<T, delete_if_not_cached<T>>`.  If you're returning a pointer into the cache, you create that pointer as:

```
    return std::unique_ptr<T, delete_if_not_cached<T>>(raw_pointer, delete_if_not_cached<T>(true));
```

to return a non-cached object, use

```
    return std::unique_ptr<T, delete_if_not_cached<T>>(new T(...))
```

One potential pitfall is that if you ever *remove* things from the cache, that might leave dangling `unique_ptr`s that you have previously returned.  If that's an issue, it probably makes more sense to use `shared_ptr`s both to return and in the cache itself.